# Why dataframe not throwing RunTimeException with "FAILFAST" option in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have the following input file, which might have bad records, I want to throw an exception and identify column name columns are not as per my custom schema.
As per my understanding data frame should immediately throw an exception even though if we do not call any action on it.

1,a,10000,11-03-2019,pune

2,b,10020,14-03-2019,pune

3,a,34567,15-03-2019,pune

tyui,a,fgh-03-2019,pune

4,b,10020,14-03-2019,pune

I have tried setting "FAILFAST" option to the spark data frame but it's not throwing any kind of exception at my end.

I have tried below code.

```
SparkSession ss = SparkSession.builder().appName("Data Quality Frameowrk")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate();

    try {
    StructField[] fields = new StructField[5];
    fields[0] = new StructField("id", DataTypes.IntegerType, false,Metadata.empty());
    fields[1] = new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty());
    fields[2] = new StructField("salary", DataTypes.DoubleType, false,Metadata.empty());
    fields[3] = new StructField("dob", DataTypes.DateType, false,Metadata.empty());
    fields[4] = new StructField("loc", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty());
    StructType customSchema = new StructType(fields);

    ss.read().format("csv")
            .schema(customSchema)
            .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
            .load("C:\\\\Users\\\\manoj.dhake\\\\Downloads\\\\softwares\\\\neo4jdata\\\\employee.csv");


    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("want to catch column name ,due to which error has been occured");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note: A Program should be able to capture the column name in case of datatype mismatch and continue the execution flow further(Should not be abnormally terminated).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because Spark is lazy, it does not even read the data when calling `load` and only processing the data frame will trigger actual reading. According to [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv-scala.collection.Seq-)

> FAILFAST : throws an exception when it meets corrupted records.

So it has nothing to do with making the load eager. The validation can be done eagerly by triggering processing manually but it will cause all the data to be processed twice in case all the entries are valid. The performance impact can be somewhat mitigated using `cache`:

```
val df = spark.read
  .schema(StructType(Seq(StructField("test", IntegerType))))
  .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
  .csv(Seq("a").toDS())
  .cache()
df.count()
```

will throw

```
aorg.apache.spark.SparkException: Malformed records are detected in record parsing. Parse Mode: FAILFAST.
```

Comment: Yes,you are right.But i do not understand what do you mean by "The validation can be done eagerly by triggering processing manually ".And though, if we do as per your code then how i would identify by which column it is failing because finally i want to log it.

Comment: By "The validation can be done eagerly by triggering processing manually " I meant calling e.g. `count` that goes through the records forcing Spark to parse and thus validate everything. AFAIK getting the problematic columns is not possible in standard Spark, the information is held in `BadRecordException` but unfortunately thrown away here https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d4d6df2f7d97168f0f3073aa42608294030ece55/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/FailureSafeParser.scala#L62 . If you happen to use databricks, there is an option called `badRecordsPath `

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just want you to point in the correct direction so that you will get the idea what kind of behavior am looking for to implement in spark. Here is link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149353/spark-read-failfast-csv-and-reread-again-in-catch-block